# Не могу создать inline_keyboard используя библиотеку telegram-bot-sdk

Tags: php, telegram, inline

Использую библиотеку https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/docs/getting-started

Создание обычной клавиатуры проходит так:

```
$keyboard = [["Меню 1","Меню 2"],["Меню 3","Меню 4"]]; 
        $reply_markup = $telegram->replyKeyboardMarkup([ 'keyboard' => $keyboard, 'resize_keyboard' => true, 'one_time_keyboard' => false ]);
        $telegram->sendMessage([ 'chat_id' => $chat_id, 'parse_mode' => 'HTML', 'text' => $reply, 'disable_web_page_preview' => true, 'reply_markup' => $reply_markup ]);
```

а вот inline_keyboard  не выходит никак создать!
Может кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 0):

```
   $inline_button1 = array("text" => "На офф сайт", "url" => "https://prepayway.com");
        $inline_button2 = array("text" => "Подробнее", "callback_data" => '/about');
        $inline_button3 = array("text" => "Не интересно", "callback_data" => '/exit');
        $inline_keyboard = [[$inline_button1, $inline_button2 ,$inline_button3 ]];
        $keyboard = array("inline_keyboard" => $inline_keyboard);
        $replyMarkup = json_encode($keyboard);
        $response = Telegram::sendMessage([
            'chat_id' =>  $chat_id,
            'text' =>  $message,
            'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
            'reply_markup' => $replyMarkup

        ]);
```

как-то так..